# Question regarding set size inside a map and vector iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, integer, set

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> suggestedProducts(vector<string>& products, string searchWord) {
        vector<vector<string>> res;
        map<string, set<string>> m;
        for (auto p : products) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= min(p.size(), searchWord.size()); ++i) {
                m[p.substr(0, i)].insert(p);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= searchWord.size(); ++i) {
            string s = searchWord.substr(0, i);
            int sz = min(m[s].size(), 3);
            vector<string> in(m[s].begin(), m[s].begin() + sz);
            res.push_back(out);
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

With the code I had above, there are two questions I wanted to ask:

1. For the `int sz = min(m[s].size(), 3)`, I got "no matching function for call to 'min'". I'm assuming it's because that sz is not an integer? And how's that? Isn't `m[s].size()` the size of the set of m[s] which is an integer?
2. For the `vector<string> in(m[s].begin(), m[s].begin() + sz)`, forget about sz being invalid, even if I just want to copy the first three elements from m[s] to vector in by doing `in(m[s].begin(), m[s].begin() + 3)`, it would give me "invalid operands to binary expression". What should I do if I just wanted to copy the first 3 elements?

Comment: For `min`, include `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: `m[s].begin() + 3` should be `std::next(m[s].begin(), 3)`

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I got "no matching function for call to 'min'" And how's that?

This means that you haven't declared a function by such name - or at least, you haven't declared such function with parameters that the arguments could be implicitly converted to.

> Isn't m[s].size() the size of the set of m[s] which is an integer?

It is.

> 2. it would give me "invalid operands to binary expression"

This is because set iterators are not random access iterators, and thus they don't support the addition operator.

> What should I do

Instead of `it + 3`, you can do `std::next(it, 3)`.

Comment: i did `int sz = min(int(m[s].size()), 3)` and it would work.

Comment: @AlanChiu That means you have declared a function named `min` that accepts two `int` arguments.